# How to use DataTable.Merge Method

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview, datatable

Goodday, Please i am trying to merge a List of dataTables into one data table. its executes without errors but returns an empty datatable. I am not able to give comprehensive code her because of multiple classes and methods but this is what i have.

```
List<DataTable> DataTableList = new List<DataTable>();

//fills the list of datatables with a method in another class that
//access an ms access database

DataTable sumDataTableList = new DataTable();

foreach (DataTable table in DataTableList)
    { 
         sumDataTableList.Merge(table)
    }
```

The problem is that sumDataTableList is empty when displayed with a DataGridView. 
I know that some of the tables are not Empty so is the merge method overwriting instead of adding?

Thank you.

P/s : I am new to programming so please dont get irritated if you think
my question is too elementary.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make the schema of the data table sumDataTableList as the schema of the other table before start merging .
see the example

```
List<DataTable> DataTableList = new List<DataTable>();

        //fills the list of datatables with a method in another class that
        //access an ms access database

        if (DataTableList.Count > 0)
        {
            DataTable sumDataTableList = DataTableList[0].Clone();


            foreach (DataTable table in DataTableList)
            {

                sumDataTableList.Merge(table);
            }
        }
```